# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment ошибка создания видео в фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, youtube-api

Нужно сделать показ видео в фрагменте.
Фрагмент:

```
public class voina_1 extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;
    private MyPlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener;
    private YouTubePlayer player;


    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment myYouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voina_1,container, false);




        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

        playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
        playbackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();

@Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        this.player = player;
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

    private void showMessage(String message) {

    }

    private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
            // Called when playback starts, either due to user action or call to play().
            showMessage("Playing");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            // Called when playback is paused, either due to user action or call to pause().
            showMessage("Paused");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            // Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused.
            showMessage("Stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
            // Called when buffering starts or ends.
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int i) {
            // Called when a jump in playback position occurs, either
            // due to user scrubbing or call to seekRelativeMillis() or seekToMillis()
        }
    }

    private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            // Called when the player is loading a video
            // At this point, it's not ready to accept commands affecting playback such as play() or pause()
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {
            // Called when a video is done loading.
            // Playback methods such as play(), pause() or seekToMillis(int) may be called after this callback.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
            // Called when playback of an advertisement starts.
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            // Called when playback of the video starts.
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            // Called when the video reaches its end.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            // Called when an error occurs.
        }
    }
```

xml:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
                android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Class is not a View com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:604)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                         at com.whitestar.voina.voina_1.onCreateView(voina_1.java:38)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment cannot be cast to android.view.View
                                                                         at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:1380)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                         at com.whitestar.voina.voina_1.onCreateView(voina_1.java:38) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь использовать фрагмент, как `View`. так нельзя.

Comment: @metalurgus а как нужно?

Comment: Нужно почитать курс уроков по разработке для Android перед тем, как начинать что-то делать.

Comment: @metalurgus `<fragment
                android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
                android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />` так подойдет?

Comment: возможно. Никто не знает, что у вас там вообще происходит, и что вы хотите вообще сделать

Comment: @metalurgus , не работает(( нужно сделать показ видео в фрагменте

Comment: [Вот тут описание решения вашей проблемы в корне.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21304639/2667883)

Comment: @Chaynik, спасибо очень большое, сейчас буду пробывать)